# AlertController in a loop

Tags: swift, closures

I have a function to display an alert listing up to 5 items (favourites) to allow the user to select one and use it.  My code works but looks long and messy, I have tried to simplify it in a loop but the item selected by the user always returns the end of loop value.  My code is below.  It shows the loop logic I am trying to get to work (note the index returned by the alert is always the value of `counter` at the end of the loop (i.e. no matter which element is tapped, `useFavourite(5)` is called.  I have also provided the code that works (but feels messy to me).  Is there a better way of achieving simplicity?

```
    func showFavouritesAlert() -> Void {
    //either shows a list of favourites or message stating no favourites
    if userData.noFavourites {
        let message = "You have no stored favourites.  You can add to favourites by selecting the \u{2605} button."
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UK Tides", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else { //favourites are present so show them
        let message = "Select one of your Tide Station favourites."
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UK Tides", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        //the loop below shows the correct alert but always executes useFavourites(5)
        var counter = 0
        for entry in userData.currentSelection.favourites {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: entry.name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
                    self.useFavourite(counter)
            }))
            counter += 1
        }
        //the code below works but feels long winded
        let favourites = userData.currentSelection.favourites
        let favCount = favourites.count
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: favourites[0].name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
                self.useFavourite(0)
            }))
        if favCount > 1 {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: favourites[1].name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            self.useFavourite(1)
            }))
        }
        if favCount > 2 {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: favourites[2].name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            self.useFavourite(2)
            }))
        }
        if favCount > 3 {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: favourites[3].name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            self.useFavourite(3)
            }))
        }
        if favCount > 4 {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: favourites[4].name, style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            self.useFavourite(4)
            }))
        }
        //the code above works


        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly better ways to do this (e.g. using `.enumerated()` instead of a manual counter), but to answer your question, your closure has to capture the *value* instead of capturing the *reference* (which is the default for local variables).

```
var counter = 0
for entry in userData.currentSelection.favourites {
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: entry.name, style: .default) { [counter] _ in
        self.useFavourite(counter)
    }
    alertController.addAction(action)
    counter += 1
}
```

See [Capture Lists](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID544).

And the version without a local variable:

```
for (offset, entry) in userData.currentSelection.favourites.enumerated() {
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: entry.name, style: .default) { _ in
        self.useFavourite(offset)
    }
    alertController.addAction(action)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, that works.  And thanks for the reference to Capture Lists - which helps me understand why!

Comment: @JimBurke Unfortunately, the information about capture lists is rather hidden in the Swift Guide therefore most people use only the common `[weak self]`.

Comment: Yes, I do remember reading it but didn't really grasp how I would use it.  The enumerations pointer is handy too - thanks twice!